# rapidxml comparing node values (testing values)

Tags: c++, rapidxml

Im new to radidxml, I cant find a way to compare a node value to string.

The only way I can figure out is to print it to a string, then test that value.

```
if (cell_node->first_node("text:p")) {
  std::string test;
  print(test.begin(), *cell_node->first_node("text:p")->first_node(), 0);
  if (test[0] == '#') {
    std::cout << "TRUE";
    cell_node->first_node("text:p")->remove_first_node();
    rapidxml::xml_node<> *node3 = doc.allocate_node(
            rapidxml::node_data, 0, "append this one"
    );
    cell_node->first_node("text:p")->append_node(node3);
  }
}
```

Is there any other way? I was hoping for:

```
cell_node->first_node("text:p")->first_node()->value() == "some string";
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `node->value()`, surely?

```
xml_node n = cell_node->first_node("text:p"); // don't keep calling first_node

if (n && (n->value()[0] == '#'))
{ 
  ...
```

It returns `char*` rather than `std::string`, so beware comparing the values of two nodes...

The RapidXml manual is here: http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html - Plenty of simple examples.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the node, you can call name() to get its name as pointer to string.

```
if (0 == strcmp(node->name(), "#"))
{
    cout << "Found the # node!" << endl;
}
```